# Loading XML and XSL files in PHP

Tags: php, xml, xslt

I am developing an application in PHP were I use XML and XSL files. How can I load a XML file into a $xml variable and a XSL file into a $xsl variable?

Answer (score 3):

Simple example here

```
$proc = new XSLTProcessor();

$xsl = new DOMDocument();
$xsl->load("your.xsl");  // load XSL

$xml = new DOMDocument(); 
$xml->load("your.xml");  // load XML

$proc->importStylesheet($xsl);
echo $proc->transformToXML($xml); // transform XML
```

[XSL docs are here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php)

Comment: when I try to do it this way the result is a fatal error because DOMDocument class was not found, any solution?

Comment: @Haritz refer to the documentation - the [installation docs are here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dom.setup.php)

Comment: the question is by running phpinfo() I can see dom is intalled and enabled. I dont know why I cant run DOMDocument()

Answer (score 1):

As for your XML question, have a look at PHPs SimpleXML class. Here is a detailed tutorial explaining how to load an XML file and how to start parsing it:

[Parsing XML with the SimpleXML class](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-To-SimpleXML-With-PHP.html#3)